# \texttt does not break in two lines

Tags: formatting, text, text-decorations

I use `\texttt` to format some text. I need to break it into two lines if it exceeds the line width. I use `\justify` but it does not always work. The script below shows two examples one works well and the other does not. Can you identify why `\justify` does not work in one case?

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\author{First Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{First University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}
\email{mail@mail.com}

\author{Second Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Second University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}
\email{mail2@mail.com}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\lipsum

\texttt{\justify{xxxx:xxxx;yyyyyyyyy:yy-yy-yyyy;zzzzzzz:zz-zz-zzzz;uuu-uuuuu:uuuuuu-uuuuuu;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:a;cccccc:c;wwwwww:wwwwww@qqqq.qqq}}

\texttt{\justify{long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which one works? The second one?

Comment: note you have defined `\justify` with no argument so should be `\justify  xxx...` not `\justify{xxx....}`

Comment: Your first example has very few possible break points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\author{First Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{First University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}
\email{mail@mail.com}

\author{Second Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Second University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}
\email{mail2@mail.com}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\lipsum

\begin{flushleft}

\path|xxxx:xxxx;yyyyyyyyy:yy-yy-yyyy;zzzzzzz:zz-zz-zzzz;uuu-uuuuu:uuuuuu-uuuuuu;aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:a;cccccc:c;wwwwww:wwwwww@qqqq.qqq|

\path|long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-long-text-|

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```